# Laravel - After login doesn't redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, http-status-code-302

When i logged in i can't redirect to page. In inspector network the page shows but with a 302 found code.

[image]

The auth::attempt() and auth::check() returns both true when i do dd().

My code is this:

```
    Route::post('/login', function()
{
  //echo "login...";
  $username = Input::get('username');
  $password = Input::get('password');
  $remember = Input::get('remember');

  $userdata = array(
    'username'  => Input::get('username'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password')
  );
  $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|exists:us,username',
        'password' => 'required'
  );

  $validator = Validator::make($userdata, $rules);

  if ($validator->passes())
  {
    //dd(Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password], $remember));
    if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password], $remember))
    {
      //echo "ok";
      //dd(Auth::check());
      return Redirect::to('app/');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //echo "error";
    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like that redirect is fine, but then app/groups then does another redirect.

Comment: I have a route app/groups that return a view.

Comment: So? Yout can see from your network tab you get redirected from login to /app/groups. So that's working. Something is redirecting you back _after_ you've redirected to /app/groups.

Comment: I edit the code to see the else... now i'returning to /app to test and works but because route app/ don't have middleware('auth')

Comment: If you have a new / different question, create a new question, don't try to rehash an existing one.

Comment: I just put the full code. the question is the same.

Comment: Except now the code doesn't match your screenshot and doesn't resemble the previous code! I'm out.

Comment: provide the related route

Comment: I'm sorry but you see the if that i have putted inside the if $validator->passes(). Like i said i just put the full code to try explain better my problem. The problem is the same, the initial code is there, but ok. I'm not going to discuss these kinds of issues that should not be a problem for me.
Thanks anyway

Comment: i want to redirect to app/groups and my route is that: Route::get('app/groups', function()
{
return view('app.main-folders');
})->middleware('auth');
@RimonKhan

Comment: try this: `return Redirect::to('app/groups');`

Comment: go back to login... if i put dd(Auth::check()) returns true

Comment: remove this code from your route `->middleware('auth'); `

Comment: if i remove this redirect well. but then I am not using authentication. Anyone who posts the link enters.

Comment: create a route group and put the code inside the group route the add middleware on the group.

Comment: @user3242861 I posted a answer try this.

Comment: don't work. Stay equal.

Comment: @user3242861 Is your login route (`Route::post('/login'..`) has any middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('app/groups', function() { 
        return view('app.main-folders'); 
    });
});
```

[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-middleware)

Comment: I try this but the problem continue.

Comment: try this: inside Auth::attempt() `dd(Auth::user())` and show me dd result

Comment: i want to see your full route.php

Comment: before` POST` login route comment this code: `Auth::routes();` and try again.

Comment: don't work yet! I commented Auth::routes(); and uncomment Route::get('/login', function()
{
    return view('auth.login');
});

Comment: Have any more idea about the cause of the problem?